# Unalias command in ARMv7?

Tags: assembly, arm, armv7, armasm

I am programming the Stellaris LM3S9B92 Evalbot in assembly language (from what I gather, ARMv7 or a variety of it).

I use aliases a lot, as I find they make my code more readable. Typically, to signal that my register r2 contains a waiting value, I use :

`alias r2, delay`

I would like to remove that alias later in the program. Is there an "unalias" command, similar to the ".unreq" I had for my Raspberry Pi ?

EDIT : From my manual [here](https://www.egr.msu.edu/classes/ece480/capstone/spring10/group07/480STUFF/spms180d.pdf), I gather that the flavour of Assembly language used is Thumb-2

Comment: It's more about which flavour of assembler, not the version of the target ARM architecture.  I think you're using armasm, as opposed to the GNU assembler.  But I'm not sure, so edit the question with details of which assembler software you're using.

Comment: FWIW that is a cortex-m3 which is ARMv7m not ARMv7

Comment: The raspberry pis started off with ARMv6 which the zero still is and then briefly had some ARMv7's and then landed on ARMv8s which have an ARMv7 compatibility mode.  So there is some overlap from ARMv7 raspberry pi code you may have written to the thumb2 extensions you may find in a cortex-m3, but I would be very careful (a good assembler should help you).  And as answered above it sounds like you are talking about assembler specific stuff (armasm) rather than the arm instruction sets anyway...

Comment: have you read the documentation for the assembler (tool) you are using?  assembly language is defined by the assembler not the processor vendors instruction set documentation (in general).

Comment: @Peter Cordes : Thank you, I updated the question. Is the editing software relevant too? I am using Keil υVision 4.

Comment: Keil uVision is an IDE, right?  Editor + assembler.  The assembler part matters, but the editor part doesn't.  You could edit your source with any text editor, it just matters what assembler you're using to assemble `.asm` into binary object files.

Comment: Unless it's configured oddly uVision uses the ARM compiler toolchain and armasm.  (ARM owns Keil.)